# "ls" with one-digit pattern gives me strange results

Tags: ls

I'm running Ubuntu as VM in VMWare Fusion on MacPro:

```
ayakovlev@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.11.10.3 #1 SMP Thu Mar 6 15:31:54 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The command below outputs result which I expect:

```
ayakovlev@ubuntu:~$ ls /usr/include/*5*
ax25.h
```

When I replace `5` by `6` I get very strange results:

```
ayakovlev@ubuntu:~$ ls /usr/include/*6*
a.out.h  asm  bits  c++  fpu_control.h  gnu  ieee754.h  sys  zconf.h
```

What might be a reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sparhawk explained, what is happening is that you are listing the content of the directories. This will not depend on the *nix you are using, as far as I know, this is the default behavior of GNU `ls`. Non-GNU implementations may be different but I doubt it.

When you run this command:

```
ls /usr/include/*6*
```

The glob (`*6*`) is expanded by your shell (bash for example) *before* calling `ls`. So, given the following directory structure:

```
.
├── dir1
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
└── dir2
    ├── file1
    └── file2
```

`ls d*` will be expanded to `ls dir1 dir2`, and give the results you expect:

```
dir1:
file1  file2

dir2:
file1  file2
```

This is how `ls` deals with *multiple* target directories by default, it lists each directory found and then the contents of that directory. However, if you run it on a single directory, the name is not printed:

```
$ ls d*1
file1  file2
```

So, since there is only one match for the glob `*6*` in `/usr/include` and that match is a directory, you are running `ls` with a single directory as input and, therefore, it is listing the contents of the directory without including the directory name.

Answer (score 6):

The wildcards in `ls /usr/include/*6*` expand to whatever matches. In the first case, it matched specific regular files. However, if it matches directories such as `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`, it'll print out the contents of those directories instead (i.e. it would have expanded to `ls /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`).

You can verify that the wildcard would have expanded to a directory with `ls /usr/include | grep 6`.

Comment: To list directories entries instead of its contents you can use `-d`: `ls -d /usr/include/*6*`.

Comment: In all other Unixes I worked the `ls` used to show a directory before list of files from *this* directory. Including the Mac OS X, where I can see a bunch of directories, containing the digit `6`, followed by files from these directories.

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev I see the same thing in Ubuntu, but only if there are multiple matches for the wildcard. If the wildcard only matches one item, and it is a directory, it won't list the directory name before listing the contents.